# Keydown event inside onSelectRow method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have this code in my JQuery grid:

```
onSelectRow:function(rowid){
    var r=$("#myGrid").getRowData(rowid);
    var col1 = r.column1;
    $("#myGrid #"+rowid).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 46) { 
            alert(col1);
        }
    });
}
```

my actual purpose is to delete the selected row record in database when `[delete]` key is pressed on the keyboard.

I am testing the code with `alert()`, as given code above.

The problem is, whenever I clicked on the same row multiple times, say 4 times, followed by single `[delete]` key press, the alert popup 4 times. However, it works fine when I clicked 4 different rows, followed by single `[delete]` key press.

This is the illustration of the situation(clicked rows, followed by `[delete]`):

```
   clicked row(in sequence)                alert popups   

   row1 ->[delete]                         row1
   row1, row2, row3, row4 ->[delete]       row4   
   row1, row1, row1, row2 ->[delete]       row2    
   row1, row2, row3, row3 ->[delete]       row3, row3    
   row1, row2, row2, row2 ->[delete]       row2, row2, row2    
   row1, row1, row1, row1 ->[delete]       row1, row1, row1, row1
```

Why and how to overcome this problem? Or maybe there is another better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each time You select a row, You're registering a keydown event listener.
Perhaps should You take your keydown event handler out like this:

```
$("#myGrid tr").keyup(function(e) {
    var rowid = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
    var r=$("#myGrid").getRowData(rowid);
    var col1 = r.column1;
    if(e.keyCode == 46) {
        alert(col1);
    }
});
```

EDIT: If your grid is generated dynamically:

```
$("#myGrid").on("keyup", "tr", function(e) {
    var rowid = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
    var r=$("#myGrid").getRowData(rowid);
    var col1 = r.column1;
    if(e.keyCode == 46) {
        alert(col1);
    }
});
```

You may need to somehow check that the row is selected.

Comment: I've tried this before I came with my above code, also no luck.

Comment: Try the second version I've just added

Comment: The second one works nicely. I've removed `parseInt()` since `id` values includes some `char`. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be happening is when you click a row, `onSelectRow` is called. In this function you bind a `keydown` event on row. So, when you click the row 4 times, `onSelectRow` will be called 4 times, this will in-turn bind the event 4 times and so you see an `alert` 4 times.

Solution is NOT to bind the `keydown` event inside `onSelectRow` function. You should rather bind `keyup` outside `onSelectRow` function this way :

```
 $("#myGrid someRowSelector").keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 46) { 
            alert(col1);
        }
    });
```

Where `someRowSelector` identifies the rows to bind events on.

Comment: i've changed to `keyup`, the problem is still the same.

Comment: @RafaEl Just changing to `keyup` is not sufficient you need to take it out of `onSelctRow` to avoid multiple binding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `keydown` event try `keyup` event

```
onSelectRow:function(rowid){
    var r=$("#myGrid").getRowData(rowid);
    var col1 = r.column1;
    $("#myGrid #"+rowid).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 46) { 
            alert(col1);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Register one `keydown`-listener and then loop through a list of elements.

This is how I would do this:

```
var colsToDelete = {};

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 46) {
        for(var id in colsToDelete) {
            var data = colsToDelete[id];
            alert(data);
        }
        colsToDelete = {};
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

And your code looks like this:

```
onSelectRow:function(rowid){
    var r = $("#myGrid").getRowData(rowid);
    colsToDelete[rowid] = r.column1;
}
```

Comment: Then how do you know `[delete]` key is pressed?

Comment: sorry, I missed it (I added it in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to modify the plugin you can make extend function for your jqgrid like this.

```
 $.extend($.fn.jqGrid, {
         bindKeysCustom: function (settings) {
            var o = $.extend({
                onEnter: null,
                onSpace: null,
                onLeftKey: null,
                onRightKey: null,
                onSupr: null,
                scrollingRows: true
            }, settings || {});
            return this.each(function () {
                var $t = this;
                if (!$('body').is('[role]')) { $('body').attr('role', 'application'); }
                $t.p.scrollrows = o.scrollingRows;
                $($t).keydown(function (event) {
                    var target = $($t).find('tr[tabindex=0]')[0], id, r, mind,
                    expanded = $t.p.treeReader.expanded_field;
                    //check for arrow keys
                    if (target) {
                        mind = $t.p._index[$.jgrid.stripPref($t.p.idPrefix, target.id)];
                        if (event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 39 || event.keyCode === 40) {
                            // up key
                            if (event.keyCode === 38) {
                                r = target.previousSibling;
                                id = "";
                                if (r) {
                                    if ($(r).is(":hidden")) {
                                        while (r) {
                                            r = r.previousSibling;
                                            if (!$(r).is(":hidden") && $(r).hasClass('jqgrow')) { id = r.id; break; }
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        id = r.id;
                                    }
                                }
                                $($t).jqGrid('setSelection', id, true, event);
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                            //if key is down arrow
                            if (event.keyCode === 40) {
                                r = target.nextSibling;
                                id = "";
                                if (r) {
                                    if ($(r).is(":hidden")) {
                                        while (r) {
                                            r = r.nextSibling;
                                            if (!$(r).is(":hidden") && $(r).hasClass('jqgrow')) { id = r.id; break; }
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        id = r.id;
                                    }
                                }
                                $($t).jqGrid('setSelection', id, true, event);
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                            // left
                            if (event.keyCode === 37) {
                                if ($t.p.treeGrid && $t.p.data[mind][expanded]) {
                                    $(target).find("div.treeclick").trigger('click');
                                }
                                $($t).triggerHandler("jqGridKeyLeft", [$t.p.selrow]);
                                if ($.isFunction(o.onLeftKey)) {
                                    o.onLeftKey.call($t, $t.p.selrow);
                                }
                            }
                            // right
                            if (event.keyCode === 39) {
                                if ($t.p.treeGrid && !$t.p.data[mind][expanded]) {
                                    $(target).find("div.treeclick").trigger('click');
                                }
                                $($t).triggerHandler("jqGridKeyRight", [$t.p.selrow]);
                                if ($.isFunction(o.onRightKey)) {
                                    o.onRightKey.call($t, $t.p.selrow);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                            //check if enter was pressed on a grid or treegrid node
                        else if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                            $($t).triggerHandler("jqGridKeyEnter", [$t.p.selrow]);
                            if ($.isFunction(o.onEnter)) {
                                o.onEnter.call($t, $t.p.selrow);
                            }
                        } else if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                            $($t).triggerHandler("jqGridKeySpace", [$t.p.selrow]);
                            if ($.isFunction(o.onSpace)) {
                                o.onSpace.call($t, $t.p.selrow);
                            }
                        } else if (event.keyCode === 46) {
                            $($t).triggerHandler("jqGridKeySupr", [$t.p.selrow]);
                            if ($.isFunction(o.onSupr)) {
                                o.onSupr.call($t, $t.p.selrow);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Then, instead call your jqgrid like this

```
  grid.jqGrid('bindKeys');
```

You have to call it like this

```
grid.jqGrid('bindKeysCustom', {
                'onSupr': function (rowid) { }
            });
```